# Designing GDT for a small kernel

Tags: x86, kernel, memory-segmentation

I am currently writing some small kernel code. The following is what I have copied from a kernel project somewhere. It contains code for loading the kernel to memory location 0x1000 and jumping to the location 0x1000:

```
;
; The Bootsector Code (First 512 bytes of the floppy)
;

;
; Define Code Segment and Data Segment Rights details for inputting to GDTFill function
;
%define CS_ACCES 10011011b ; CS and DS Access Rights (Details in GDT.INC)
%define DS_ACCES 10010011b

;
;  16 Bit Addressing initially
;
[bits 16]

;
; Code begins at 0x7c00
;
[org 0x7c00]

;
; Bios Jumps to 0xf000:0xffff
; Then it loads the first 512 bytes (BootSector) 
;  from first boot device to 0x0000:0x7c00
;

jmp boot


;
; Includes
;
%include "GDT.INC"


;
; Define Stack 
;
boot:
mov ax,0x07C0 
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov ax,0x8FFF 
mov ss,ax


;
; Stack begins at 0xf000 and fills from there downwards
;
mov sp,0xFFFF 


;
; Note:
; Linear Address = Shift Segment by 1 byte and add Offset to it
;
; Read Kernel From Floppy to Memory location es:bx (0x1000 here)
; Cylinder Head Sector and Buffer are as follows:
; 
; es:bx - buffer where to load Kernel to
; ch    - track number
; cl    - starting sector
; dh    - head number
; dl    - drive number (0 here)
; Then call interrupt 0x13 
; 

xor ax,ax
int 0x13

;
; Do the floppy int 13 reading
;
push es 

mov ax,0x100
mov es,ax
mov bx,0

mov ah,2
mov al,30
mov ch,0
mov cl,2
mov dh,0
mov dl,0
int 0x13

;
; Now es holds stack addresss
;
pop es

;
; Fill GDT
; Refer to GDT.INC for details
;
GDTFill 0, 0xFFFFF,CS_ACCES,1101b,gdt_cs
GDTFill 0, 0xFFFFF,DS_ACCES,1101b,gdt_ds

;
; Store Limit of GDT beginning at location marked as gdtptr
; This has to be passed on to lgdt instruction
;
mov ax, gdtend
mov bx, gdt
sub ax,bx
mov word [gdtptr], ax

;
; Store Linear address of GDT at gdtptr after allowing space for the previous data
; Linear Address = Shift Segment by 1 byte and add Offset to it
;
xor ax,ax 
mov ax,ds 
mov bx,gdt
call LinearAdd
mov dword [gdtptr+2], ecx 

;
; Load gdt using lgdt. Disable interrupts before that
;
cli
lgdt[gdtptr]

;
; Move to protected mode. Set cr0's first bit to 1 by or'ing it
;
mov eax,cr0
or ax,1
mov cr0,eax

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; Once in Protected Mode,
; Except cs all are defined w.r.t DataSegment
; DataSegment Descriptor from beginning of GDT is 8 bytes
; CodeSegment Descriptor from beginning of GDT is 10 bytes
; Stack (Very important! - This is what i messed with initially:
; --------------------------------------------------------------
; Defined w.r.t Data segment
; Beginning - 0x9f000 (Fills downwards)
; Stack size is  = 0x9f000 - DataSegment Value (= 0x0) (Have to change this)
; Quite enough for some small operations and LIBC Functions
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
jmp next

next:
mov ax,0x10
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov fs,ax
mov gs,ax
mov ss,ax 

mov esp,0x9F000 ; Stack begins filling at this address

;
; protected mode segmented address = cs:0x1000
; This is nothing but 0x0:0x1000 in protected mode (Have to change these)
; Which is where kernel was loaded earlier from floppy
;
jmp dword 0x8:0x1000

end:
jmp end ; Just in case it slips the earlier step !

;
; Initially fill GDT with 0's
; 
gdt:
gdt_null:
dw 0,0,0,0
gdt_cs:
dw 0,0,0,0
gdt_ds:
dw 0,0,0,0
gdtend:


;
; The following is the GDT Pointer
; This is used for passing it on to LGDT Instruction
;
gdtptr:
dw 0x0000 ; 16 bit size of GDT
dd 0 ; 32 bit linear address of GDT


;
; Filling the rest of space with NOP
; Or else boot sector might start executing invalid instructions there
; Because of Junk Data
;
times 510-($-$$) db 144
;
; The signature of boot sector
;
dw 0xaa55
```

The following is in GDT.INC:

```
; Calculate Linear Address
; Called with following Values:
;       ax - has segment number
;   bx - has offset number
; 
; Output:
;   ecx - has Linear Address
; 
; We are in 16 bit mode
;
; Linear Address = Shift Segment by 1 byte and add Offset to it
; So 0x07c0:0x0  = 0x7c00

LinearAdd:
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov cx,ax
    shl ecx,4
    and ebx,0x0000FFFF
    add ecx,ebx
    ret


; Filling Global Descriptor Table
; -------------------------------
;
; Note:
; -----
; 1. Order of variables input: Base (32 bits), 
;     Limit (20 bits), Access Rights(8 bits), Flags(4 bits), Segment Address 
;     (32 bits)
; 
; 2. Variables input to function are moved LS 4 bits First (Right to Left) to table
;
; 3. While reading LS 4 bits or MS 4 bits, read from left to right
;
; Base:
; -----
; Bits in Table          Bits in Field 'Base'        Location w.r.t Beginning of Segment
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; 16 - 31                0  - 15                     +2 (2 bytes in length)
; 32 - 39                16 - 23                     +4 (1 byte in length)
; 55 - 63                24 - 31                     +7 (1 byte in length)
;
;
; Howto:
; ------
;
; Below %5 ie., the fifth variable input to function GDTFill is Beginning of GDT's Code Segment
; [%5+2] represents entry 1 in above table
; [%5+4] represents entry 2 in above table
; [$5+7] represents entry 3 in above table
; Entry 1 is 2 bytes (so ax is moved to word [%5+2]
; Entry 2 and 3 are 1 byte (so al is moved to byte[%5+4] and [%5+7] respectively
;
; Limit:
; ------
;
; Bits in Table          Bits in Field 'Limit'        Location w.r.t Beginning of Segment
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; 0  -  15               0 -  15                       +0 (2 bytes in length)
; 16 -  20               48 - 51                       +6 (1 byte in length)
; 
; Refer 'Howto' above for detailed description
;
; Access Rights:
; --------------
; 
; Access Rights (Bit 40 to Bit 47) = Type (Bit 40 to Bit 43) + System Flag (Bit 44) + DPL (Bit 45 and 46) + Reserved (Bit 47); 
; Type        - Your Call (Say A is Kernel Code and B is User code (Here it is 11 and 3 respectively)
; System Flag - Both Code and Data Segment have S Flag = 1
; DPL         - Privilege level (Ring 0 or 3?) (Ring 0 - 00 and Ring 3 - 11)
; 
; Flags:
; ------
; G B O AVL
;
; G   - Granularity = 1 here (means Segment Size is 4096 bytes)
; B   - Address offsets used for accessing segments are 32 bits long
; O   - 0 (Don't know what it is!)
; AVL - 1 here (You Can Ignore it)
;
; 

%macro GDTFill  5   
    push eax
; Base
    mov eax,%1
    mov word [%5+2],ax
    shr eax,16         ; Shift Right to 
    mov byte [%5+4],al
    shr eax,8
    mov byte [%5+7],al
; Limit
    mov eax,%2
    and eax,0x000FFFFF
    mov word [%5],ax    ; ecrit (0..15)
    shr eax,16          ; place (16..19) sur le nibble inferieur
    mov byte [%5+6],0   ; initialise flags+lim(16..19) a 0
    or [%5+6],al        ; ecrit (16..19)
; flags :
    mov al,%4
    and al,0x0F
    shl al,4
    or [%5+6],al
; acces :
    mov byte [%5+5],%3
    pop eax
%endmacro
```

The above worked for a long time. However, when my kernel started becoming bigger, the data and code segments overlapped. Though both are starting at 0, the data in the data segment overlapped with the code in code segment or something like that. Because of this, I was not able to print messages completely.

Is there a way to change the base address of data segment and code segment such that there is some space between the bases to write a small kernel of about max 1 MB in size in binary?

I have attached the link to the kernel and describing the problem in detail below:

1. I make the kernel using:

   ```
   make clean; make
   ```

inside src folder

1. Boot it in qemu using:

   ```
   sudo qemu-system-i386 -net nic,vlan=0,model=pcnet -net tap,vlan=0,ifname=tap,script=no -fda ../flp/fileb.flp -boot a  -m 128
   ```
2. After booting, I run the following command to verify the string operations:

   ```
   testnum
   ```
3. Then I run the following command, and I see that messages are stripped in between and not printed after a certain line:

   ```
   pcnetops
   ```
4. If I comment the following lines in console.c, and run pcnetops, I get all the stuff printed:

   ```
   print( "sizeof(char) == ");
   print(htos(sizeof(char)));
   print(CRLF);

   print("htos(stoh(ffffffff, LEFT_TO_RIGHT)): ");
   print(htos(stoh((unsigned char *) "ffffffff", LEFT_TO_RIGHT)));
   print(CRLF);
   ```

This is the reason why I doubt I should possibly be separating code segment and data segment base addresses (as of now both are 0)

Comment: There probably is, but first you have to figure out and tell us the details of the problem and how you compile/link the rest of the code that you think is too big "or something like that". I don't think the posted code alone is very helpful.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for looking at the stuff; Here is my code: http://code.google.com/p/fuzz-kernel/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc ; Please excuse me for my ignorance in many areas of coding, as I am very new to low level C coding; I am trying to learn stuff by going through tutorials

Comment: The question is actually about how to setup the segments.  You should probably change the title and the tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following in your code:

```
gdt_cs:
dw 0,0,0,0
gdt_ds:set
dw 0,0,0,0
```

What you need to do is to modify the descriptors to include the base, which is currently set to 0.  You can use this image as a guide:

[image: Structure of GDT entry]

By setting the base and limit appropriately, you can ensure that CS and DS don't overlap.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, (GDTFill 0, 0xFFFFF,CS_ACCES,1101b,gdt_cs) and (GDTFill 0,0xFFFFF,DS_ACCES,1101b,gdt_ds) lines are used in the code to fill in the values for base and limit

Comment: I tried sending different values. Read somewhere that the max value that can be stored in ax is 0xFFFF. Hence I could address a max of 0xFFFFF (segment 0xFFFF and offset 0xF) in real mode. Tried some combinations and it did not work. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: You're confusing two modes.  If you're in Real Mode, you don't need a GDT or any segment descriptors.  `mov cs, ax` will set csbase to `eax << 4` and the limit to `0xffff`. If, on the other hand, you are in protected mode, then `mov cs, ax` will use `ax` as a pointer into the GDT, and read the selector from there, with a 32-bit base and a 20-bit limit (possibly shifted left by 12 bits).  Which mode are you in?

Comment: Initially the OS is in real mode. After executing **mov cr0,eax**, it is changing to protected mode as per my understanding.

Comment: So what you need to do is to setup the GDT in real mode, then after you switch to protected mode, you should reload the segments, which will be loaded from the GDT this time.  It seems to me like your question is about setting up segments in protected mode so that they don't overlap.  If you're talking about real mode, then it doesn't really matter, because you can use `eax` which can access all 32 bits even if the segment base is 0.

Comment: Yes, it is about setting up protected mode so that the segments don't overlap.

Comment: Ah, finally after putting heart and soul on this. It was a silly mistake. Found that the floppy was not being read completely. After reading a few more sectors (in the int 13 call), it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the fact that all the floppy sectors were not being read in the int 13 call. Increased the value of al to 40 (from 30 - number of sectors read) and then compiled again. Now it is working fine. I understand that the problem has not been fully solved in the right way though :)